# AppBar not showing on right-click in win 8 app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing a windows 8 metro style app in HTML/JavaScript.
I want to activate AppBar on Right-click but it is only appearing when Win logo+Z keys are pressed.

Here's the code i'm using:

```
<div id="appBar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar" data-win-options="">
        <button 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" 
            data-win-options="{id:'clr',label:'Restart',icon:'refresh',
                section:'global',tooltip:'Restart'}" name="clr" onclick="clear()">
        </button>

        <hr 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" 
            data-win-options="{type:'separator',section:'global'}" />       
        <button 
            data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" 
            data-win-options="{id:'help',label:'Instruction',icon:'info',
                section:'global',tooltip:'Read help'}"
             name="btnIns" onclick="display()" >
        </button>
    </div>
```

What do I need to change??
Thanks in advance,
Moin

Comment: Your code works fine for me, the app bar is working as rexpected on right click. Maybe something else is wrong? Do you have another div with the id `appBar` somewhere? Where is your code placed?

Comment: @DavidMüller I Don't have any other `appBar` id anywhere in code. Code is placed in default.html

Comment: Does the error console reveal anything? As I said, your appbar works flawlessly when I just tested it. Have you checked out http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-bar-sample-a57eeae9 ?

Comment: You are processing it / causing the appbar control to be instantiated, rightly?

Comment: @DominicHopton I've just added the code to body section. I don't have any other Javascrpt code that handles appbar. I'm a newbie in win 8.

Comment: If you are using the default template, you should have a default.js file -- in that file will be a call to WinJS.UI.processAll(). That's the magic you need. :)

Comment: @DominicHopton But it's already there. `app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
                // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            } else {
                // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            }
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
        }`
Do I need to add it again anywhere?

Comment: Nope, that should be fine. Put a breakpoint in the constructor of the Appbar (in ui.js) and see if it's actually getting called.

you don't have anything else capturing moue input do you?

Comment: @DominicHopton how do i put the break point and what is it? Please guide me.

Comment: Open up UI.js, look for "AppBar: WinJS.Class.derive"  -- this will get you to the constructor of the AppBar, and you should be able to set the breakpoint in it and see if it gets called.

If it doesn't enable the breakpoint, set a breakpoint on the first line of default.js, and *then* set the breakpoint.